# Jenkins plugin recomendation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus

My company wants to visualize the % of failed/successful deployments of jenkins jobs.

And the way jenkins is arranged complicates the task, each team or project is a folder name and inside the project folder the jobs are called same.

Folder1
   samejobname
   subfolder1
      jobname
folder2
   samejobname
   subfolder1
      jobname
.
.
.
folderN
   samejobname
   subfolder1
   .
   .
   .
   subfolderN

So I need a plugin (there must be one) which can give me this stats of each job so I can take it from API and pull them to prometheus somehow.

I will be very very happy to be pointed in the right direction so thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: hygieia is a devops dashboard with a plugin for Jenkins https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia/tree/master/hygieia-jenkins-plugin

Comment: Allure framework is pretty good
https://github.com/allure-framework
http://allure.qatools.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use grafana for the dashboard? If so, you can customize with the [prometheus plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Prometheus+Plugin)
See also: https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/visualizing-jenkins-pipeline-results-in-grafana/

Comment: This is the aproach we are going but with prometheus instead of influxdb. It took me a while to get that prometheus pull metrics and you don't push them to it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Summary Display plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin). Some more details about it (= quote from the linked page):

> ... allows an easy and fully customized build report display.
>
> Features
>
> - Allow a rich summary report visible from both project and build page
> - Reports must be written in an XML format according to the syntax described in section Syntax Description
> - This plugin allow the parsing of several XML files
> - Reports displayed are ordered according to the XML file names
> - Element displayed are based on

In general, the answer to such questions is usually found by searching the endless [Jenkins plugin index](https://plugins.jenkins.io/).